# How to rewrite this code to pointers in C

Tags: c, pointers

i need to rewrite this code to pointers (use pointers (without index), instead of that code).

```
r[k] = p[i][j];  -----> *r = *p

scanf("%d", &r[k]);   ------> scanf ("%s",r )

scanf("%d", &p[i][j]); ----> scanf (( *(x + i) + j ))
```

Is this good rewriten?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems you mean the following

```
r[k] = p[i][j];  -----> *( r + k ) = *( *( p + i ) + j )

scanf("%d", &r[k]);   ------> scanf ("%d", r + k )

scanf("%d", &p[i][j]); ----> scanf ( "%d", *(p + i) + j )
```

Here is a demonstrative program

```
#include <stdio.h>

#define N   2

int main(void) 
{
    int r[N];
    int p[N][N] =
    {
        { 1, 2 },
        { 3, 4 }
    };

    size_t k = 1;
    size_t i = 1, j = 1;

    *( r + k ) = *( *( p + i ) + j );

    printf( "r[%zu] = %d\n", k, r[k] );

    scanf ( "%d", r + k );      //  Enter 10

    printf( "r[%zu] = %d\n", k, r[k] );

    scanf ( "%d", *(p + i) + j );   //  Enter 20

    printf( "p[%zu][%zu] = %d\n", i, j, p[i][j] );

    return 0;
}
```

Its output is

```
r[1] = 4
r[1] = 10
p[1][1] = 20
```

Pay attention to the following quote form the C Standard (6.5.2.1 Array subscripting)

> 2 A postfix expression followed by an expression in square brackets []
>   is a subscripted designation of an element of an array object. The
>   definition of the subscript operator [] is that E1[E2] is identical to
>   (*((E1)+(E2))). Because of the conversion rules that apply to the
>   binary + operator, if E1 is an array object (equivalently, a pointer
>   to the initial element of an array object) and E2 is an integer,
>   E1[E2] designates the E2-th element of E1 (counting from zero).

Answer (score 1):

`scanf("%d", &r[k]);` will be `scanf("%d", r+k);`

`scanf("%d", &p[i][j]);` will be `scanf("%d", *(p + i) + j )`
and

`r[k] = p[i][j];`  is `*(r+k) = *(*(p+i)+j)`

`*r = *p` This is wrong. If you have a compiler try to compile this you will understand where you were wrong. You will have type mismatch.

`r` decays into pointer to first element. So

`*r = *p` will try to assign an `int[]` to `int`.